# Zend Framework 2 full configuration parameters?

Tags: configuration, parameters, module, zend-framework2

I'm trying to configure a module in Zend Framework 2 but I'm confused as to what the possible parameter names and values are.

Is there any reference for this? I've looked everywhere but cannot find anything.

Comment: Do you use the skeleton? If so, just go and replicate the Application module. And dont forget to update config/application.config.php

Comment: Can i ask what do you understand of configuring a `Module`? A module can be a lot but can be just 20 lines of Module.php, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear.  Are you trying to configure a module written by someone else, or are you asking about how to make your own module provide user-friendly configuration?

Both questions get answered by understanding how configuration works.

In a well-designed module, you'll usually have a `config` directory, that will contain two files: `config/module.config.php` and `<modulename>.global.php.dist`.

`module.config.php` is for internal (private) configuration.  Someone using your module probably doesn't care about the contents.

`<modulename>.global.php.dist` contains all the configuration data that a user might want to change.  A developer using the module copies this file into `/config/autoload/<modulename>.global.php` (that path is from the top of the project, not in the module -- users of modules shouldn't ever make changes inside the module directory.)

The developer may also want to create `config/autoload/<modulename>.local.php` to override the stuff in the global file.  The skeleton application contains a .gitignore file that causes .local.php config files to be ignored.  This helps solve juggling configuration between development/staging/production and works nicely with various deployment systems.

For a slightly more expansive explanation of this stuff, see [this blog post](http://www.spiffyjr.me/2012/06/17/how-does-configuration-work-in-zf2/)